# ConcurrentDictionary TryGetValue vs []. Is [] still thread-safe?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, concurrentdictionary

I have the following `ConcurrentDictionary`:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, Session> sessions;
```

I know that `sessions.TryGetValue(key, out session)` is thread-safe, but my question is if `sessions[key]` is also thread-safe?

`sessions.TryGetValue(key, out session)` returns true or false depending on whether it was able to get the value or not.

Will `sessions[key]` return `null` if it is unable to get the value? I would think so. Can anyone confirm or shed more light on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is thread-safe, but it will not return `null`.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267253.aspx) clearly states:

> ### Exceptions
>
> KeyNotFoundException
> The property is retrieved and key does not exist in the collection.

Comment: Can you give me a link to this in the documentation, I was unable to find it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I see it is mapped to the `Item` collection. That makes sense now. I was unsure how to find this in the documentation before.

Comment: How is that clear? It only states that an exception is thrown if the key does not exist. But what happens if right at that time another thread is modifying the item at that key ?

Comment: @Chris: The whole point of the class is to be thread-safe; all operations are atomic.  The documentation explicitly states `All public and protected members of ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> are thread-safe and may be used concurrently from multiple threads. However, members accessed through one of the interfaces the ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> implements, including extension methods, are not guaranteed to be thread safe and may need to be synchronized by the caller.`

Comment: @SLaks: So, since indexer property `TValue this[ TKey key ]` is implementation of `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`'s one, it is not guaranted to be thread safe. Why do you say it is?

Comment: @BlackOverlord: That says "members accessed through one of the interfaces", not members defined by an interface.  In other words, explicit interface implementations.